# IIS 7.5 Classic ASP Error handling different from IIS 6

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, error-handling, iis-6

We are in the process of migrating an ASP Classic/ASP.NET application from IIS 6 to IIS 7.5. Most things run just fine in classic mode but we are having alot of problems with how errors are handled by IIS 7.5. We do our error reporting using a classic ASP page where we capture the error information here then redirect to a page to display the error. Based on our testing both `Server.GetLastError` and `Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")` when accessed from the logging page do not return the error details and source. Are there other ways we should retrieve the error information on IIS 7.5 or perform the logging?

In case this helps, using freb we have noticed that IIS appears to generate a completely new request then begins executing our error capturing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In addition to the answer shown below we also needed to enable 'Detailed' errors at a fine grain level to support some cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@smaclell: See http://dylanbeattie.blogspot.com/2008/12/fun-with-servergetlasterror-in-classic.html for a potential solution for you.

Here's the relevant paragraph from the article:

> There was a very similar known bug in Vista which was supposedly fixed
>   in SP1, but it looks like the same fix isn't part of Windows 2008
>   Server yet. There is a workaround, though - if you set the site's
>   default error property (under IIS settings -> Error Pages -> Edit
>   Feature Settings...) to the custom page, IIS will invoke
>   this page whenever an error is not handled by an explicitly configured
>   status-code handler (so your 404, etc. handlers will still work) - but
>   for some reason, handling the error this way means
>   Server.GetLastError() still works properly.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out. I will also add the things we have already tried to the details.

Comment: This let my ASP errors continue working. I think we still have errors with asp.net content that are resolved in an odd way but this has gotten us much much closer. Thank you for your answer.